# Property is missing in type but required in type when using Object.defineProperty

Tags: typescript, defineproperty

I have this validation middleware that I'm trying to write to validate an empty payload when sending requests :

```
const _isMissing = (body: any): boolean => !body;

export const isMissing = Object.defineProperty(_isMissing, '_apiGatewayResponse', {
  value: LAMBDA_400_RESPONSE,
});

interface ValidationFunction extends Function {
  _apiGatewayResponse: APIGatewayProxyResult;
}

export function validateRequestBody(
  handler: LambdaFunction,
  validations: Array<ValidationFunction>,
): LambdaFunction {
  const wrapper: LambdaFunction = async (
    event: APIGatewayEvent,
  ): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
    const eventBody = event.body ? JSON.parse(event.body) : null;
    for (const validation of validations) {
      const invalidBody = validation(eventBody);
      if (invalidBody) {
        return validation._apiGatewayResponse || LAMBDA_400_RESPONSE;
      }
    }

    const response = await handler(event);
    return response;
  };

  return wrapper;
}
```

But when I come to use the middleware function :

`validateRequestBody(myPostFunction, [isMissing]);`

I get a TypeScript error on `isMissing` stating

`Property '_apiGatewayResponse' is missing in type '(body: any) => boolean' but required in type 'ValidationFunction'.`

Can anyone help me resolve this? I couldn't really find any similar problems and would appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `isMissing` (which comes from `_isMissing`) is `(body: any) => boolean` (a function accepting a single parameter of type `any` and returning a `boolean`), but `ValidationFunction` requires an `_apiGatewayResponse` property on it. Even though you add the property at runtime via `Object.defineProperty`, that doesn't change the compile-time type that the function has.

You can assure TypeScript that the result has the right type via an innocuous type assertion that only asserts what you can easily see the code is adding. For example:

```typescript
type IsMissingFunction = ((body: any) => boolean) & ValidationFunction;

const _isMissing = (body: any): boolean => !body;

export const isMissing: IsMissingFunction = Object.defineProperty(
    _isMissing as typeof _isMissing & Pick<ValidationFunction, "_apiGatewayResponse">,
    '_apiGatewayResponse', {
        value: LAMBDA_400_RESPONSE
    }
);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

You *could* just use `as IsMissingFunction` instead of the more long-winded `as typeof _isMissing & Pick<ValidationFunction, "_apiGatewayResponse">`:

```typescript
type IsMissingFunction = ((body: any) => boolean) & ValidationFunction;

const _isMissing = (body: any): boolean => !body;

export const isMissing: IsMissingFunction = Object.defineProperty(
    _isMissing as IsMissingFunction,
    '_apiGatewayResponse', {
        value: LAMBDA_400_RESPONSE
    }
);
```

The reason I prefer the first version is that if you edit `IsMissingFunction` (or `ValidationFunction`) later to add more properties, TypeScript will raise a helpful error on the first example indicating that the function no longer fits the definition of `IsMissingFunction`. With the second example, you'd have to make a *really* big change for it to complain.

Comment: Thank you so much! That cleared thing up. Thanks for your help and for the detailed explanation :)